# Highlight Header View of expandable list view if Its at least one Child View is highlighted on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

I want Header View on expandable List View is automatically changed background color right after initial program if there is at least one of Child View be highlighted

[image]
I get this program from http://tutorialscache.com/expandable-listview-android-tutorials/ as an example

**Here is the ExpandableCustomAdapter Class**

```
public class ExpandableCustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

//Initializing variables
private List<String> headerData;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<ChildDataModel>> childData;
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

// constructor
public ExpandableCustomAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> headerData,
                             HashMap<String, ArrayList<ChildDataModel>> childData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.headerData = headerData;
    this.childData = childData;
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.headerData.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int headPosition) {
    return this.childData.get(this.headerData.get(headPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int headPosition) {
    return this.headerData.get(headPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int headPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.childData.get(this.headerData.get(headPosition))
            .get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int headPosition) {
    return headPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int headPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.childData.get(this.headerData.get(headPosition))
            .get(childPosition).getId();
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int headPosition, boolean is_expanded, View view, ViewGroup headGroup) {
    // Heading of each group
    String heading = (String) getGroup(headPosition);
    if (view==null){
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header,null);

    }
    TextView headerTv = view.findViewById(R.id.headerTv);
    headerTv.setText(heading+"");
    headerTv.setBackgroundColor( Color.BLUE );
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int headPosition, int childPosition, boolean islastChild, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

     ChildDataModel child = (ChildDataModel) getChild(headPosition, childPosition);

    if (view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }

    TextView childTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.childTv);
    ImageView childImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.childImg);

    childTv.setText(child.getTitle());
    if(child.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase( "China" ))
    {
        childTv.setBackgroundColor( Color.RED );
    }
    childImg.setImageResource(child.getImage());
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int headPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

**Here is ChildDataModel Class**

```
public class ChildDataModel {

long id;
int image;
String title;

public ChildDataModel(int id, String country, int image) {
     this.setId(id);
     this.setTitle(country);
     this.setImage(image);
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    Log.d("response ","ID: "+getId()+" Title: "+getTitle());
    return super.toString();
}
}
```

**Here is MainActivity Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableCustomAdapter expandableCustomAdapter;
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
List<String> headerData;
HashMap<String,ArrayList<ChildDataModel>> childData;
ChildDataModel childDataModel;
Context mContext;
ArrayList<ChildDataModel> asianCountries,africanCountries,nAmericanCountries,sAmericanCountries;
private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mContext = this;

    //initializing arraylists
    headerData = new ArrayList<>();
    childData = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<ChildDataModel>>();
    asianCountries = new ArrayList<>();
    africanCountries = new ArrayList<>();
    nAmericanCountries = new ArrayList<>();
    sAmericanCountries = new ArrayList<>();



    // link listview from activity_main.xml
    expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.expandAbleListView);

    //populating data of world continents and their countries.
    headerData.add("ASIA");

    //adding countries to Asian continent
    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Afghanistan",R.drawable.afghanistan);
    asianCountries.add(childDataModel);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(2,"China",R.drawable.china);
    asianCountries.add(childDataModel);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(3,"India",R.drawable.india);
    asianCountries.add(childDataModel);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(4,"Pakistan",R.drawable.pakistan);
    asianCountries.add(childDataModel);

    childData.put(headerData.get(0),asianCountries);


    headerData.add("AFRICA");

    //adding countries to African continent
    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"South Africa",R.drawable.southafrica);
    africanCountries.add(childDataModel);

    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(2,"Zimbabwe",R.drawable.zimbabwe);
    childData.put(headerData.get(1),africanCountries);


    headerData.add("NORTH AMERICA");
    //adding countries to NORTH AMERICA continent
    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Canada",R.drawable.canada);
    nAmericanCountries.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(2),nAmericanCountries);


    headerData.add("SOUTH AMERICA");
    //adding countries to SOUTH AMERICA continent
    childDataModel = new ChildDataModel(1,"Argentina",R.drawable.argentena);
    sAmericanCountries.add(childDataModel);
    childData.put(headerData.get(3),sAmericanCountries);



    //set adapter to list view
    expandableCustomAdapter = new ExpandableCustomAdapter(mContext,headerData,childData);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableCustomAdapter);

    //child click listener
    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int headPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                    headerData.get(headPosition)
                            + " has country "
                            + childData.get(
                            headerData.get(headPosition)).get(
                            childPosition).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    //group expanded
    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int headPosition) {
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && headPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = headPosition;
            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                    headerData.get(headPosition) + " continent expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //group collapsed
     expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
         @Override
         public void onGroupCollapse(int headPosition) {
             Toast.makeText(mContext,
                     headerData.get(headPosition) + " continent collapsed",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });

    //Group Indicator
    expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            parent.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);

            if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                ImageView imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.expandable_icon);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right));
            } else {
                ImageView imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.expandable_icon);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_down));
            }
            return false    ;
        }
    });
}
}
```

I expect to handle it without event like *setOnChildClickListener, setOnGroupExpandListener,setOnGroupCollapseListener,* etc. Thanks for help

Comment: in `getGroupView` iterate through the group's children and check if any of them needs to be highlighted. If any does - highlight the group.

Answer (score 3):

change getGroupView to:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int headPosition, boolean is_expanded, View view, ViewGroup headGroup) {
    // Heading of each group
String heading = (String) getGroup(headPosition);
if (view==null){
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header,null);

}
TextView headerTv = view.findViewById(R.id.headerTv);
headerTv.setText(heading+"");
boolean hasSelected = false;
ArrayList<ChildDataModel> childs = 
childData.get(headerData.getItemAtIndex(headPosition));
for(int i=0;i<childs.size();i++){
if(childs.get(i).isSelected){
hasSelected = true;
    }}
if(hasSelected)
headerTv.setBackgroundColor( Color.BLUE );
 else
headerTv.setBackgroundColor( Color.RED);

return view;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you most highlight the header view when getGroupView executed if childs highl sign selected chileds and if selected eny then highlight header

Comment: public class ChildDataModel {

long id;
int image;
String title; **boolean isSelected**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @hunixa siuri It does work well. However Code must be edited a little as below

```
     @Override
  public View getGroupView(int headPosition, boolean is_expanded, View view, ViewGroup headGroup) {
    // Heading of each group
    String heading = (String) getGroup(headPosition);
    if (view==null){
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header,null);

    }
    TextView headerTv = view.findViewById(R.id.headerTv);
    headerTv.setText(heading+"");
    boolean hasSelected = false;
    ArrayList<ChildDataModel> childs = childData.get(headerData.get(headPosition));
    for(int i=0;i<childs.size();i++){
        if(childs.get(i).getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase( "China" )){
            hasSelected = true;
        }}
    if(hasSelected)
        view.setBackgroundColor( Color.BLUE );
    else
        view.setBackgroundColor( Color.RED);
    return view;
}
```